# Simple math app terminated in Xcode- Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Alright, so I'm trying to do something very, very simple: Multiplying the user input from one textfield by another textfield and feeding out the answer through a label. There are no error messages, but when I try to run the app, the simulator screen goes black and Xcode says this:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key outputlabel.'

I have no idea why it is doing this. Any suggestions? Please be extremely specific as I am new to programming.

My code:

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  Cramer

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

// Objects are given addresses:


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *box_a;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *box_b;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *hiLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *clickButton;

@end
```

AND

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Cramer


#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Math takes place:

- (IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender {

    NSInteger number1 = [self.box_a.text integerValue];
    NSInteger number2 = [self.box_b.text integerValue];

    NSInteger prod = number1 * number2;

    self.hiLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(prod)];

}

@end
```

Comment: You connected an outlet in the nib which you didn't implement in code

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I have an issue though- no matter what numbers I type in, prod = 1. Why would that happen? And also how can I get the label (hiLabel) set to the answer?

Comment: *"why would that happen?"* how did you find the value of `prod`? Are you using the debugger?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Xcode. At the bottom of the screen, after the app runs, you can see "number2= 10" "number1= 12" and "prod=1". Number1 and number2 are the numbers that I typed in, but prod is always 1. Is there something I am doing wrong? I am trying to get the product of number1 and number2.

Comment: I don't really know what you're referring to, sorry - you should learn how to use debugger and see what values everything takes when you press the button.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in your view controller XIB file, created using the Interface Builder or Storyboard graphic editor, you have some view (probably a UILabel) connected to a "outputlabel" property of the File Owner (that is your ViewController class) which doesn't exist.
 Typically this happens when you initially connect an object from the XIB to a new outlet in the code, then you rename the outlet in the code but you forget to reconnect the object in the XIB to the new reanmed outlet. It could be, in your case, that you initially connected the output label to a IBOutlet property called "outputlabel", then you renamed it to "hiLabel" but you forgot to reconnect the label in the XIB to the new "hiLabel" IBOutlet.
To verify this you can look at all your objects in the view controller graphical interface, right-click on each of them and see their outlet connections and check that they point to properties effectively defined in the class.

Comment: Thank you. But now I have this problem, which is probably a result of my lack of programming knowledge: whenever I run the app, no matter which number are typed into the textfields, prod=1, not the product of the two numbers. How can I fix this? and print the actual answer to the hiLabel?

Comment: the calculation depends on the fact that the "clickButton:" method is called. This seems to be hooked to a UIButton, are you clicking this button? the calculation will take place only in such case. Also check with the debugger that the integer values returned for number1 and number2 correspond to the effective values typed in the text field

Answer (score 0):

your label on your storyboard is hooked up to a UILabel in your view controller named "outputlabel".  However in your view controller you have it named "hiLabel".  If, in interface builder, you click on your label then go to view -> utilities -> connection inspector you'll see the connections on the right hand side and should be able to verify what it's connected to.  Either delete the connection and start over or change the name of your label in your view controller.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out that that was the problem. But now, whenever I run the app, no matter which number are typed into the textfields, prod=1, not the product of the two numbers. How can I fix this? and print the actual answer to the hiLabel?

Comment: @user3587655 - Debug it.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(prod)];`, why are you using `%@`? NSInteger is a primitive type, not an object. It seems to me you should use a `%d` so that the line would read `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", prod];`.

ETA: Use `%ld` instead of `%d`.

Comment: Yep, any time you see `stringWithFormat:@"%@"` you know the author does not know what he's doing.  And the above conversion to NSNumber is even more wasted motion.